# Recursive function to calculate deposit sum after a given number of time

Tags: c++

Problem: Given a deposit amount sum, an interest rate p, and a number of time periods n, write a recursive function in C++ to calculate the sum of the deposit after n time periods, assuming the deposit earns p percent interest each period I have the code implementation but I ran into an issue because the test data I was given says The sum of the deposit is 120 when these are the inputs Input the sum: 100 Input the percent: 10 Input the periods of time: 2 but I cannot get 120 for my code I only get 352 as my answer and if I remove the sum+ in "return sum + deposit(sum, p, n - 1);" I get 121 which is the closest answers I have to 120

```
int deposit(int sum, int p, int n) {
    if (n == 0) {
        return sum;
    }
    else {
        int interest = sum * p / 100;
        sum += interest;
        return sum + deposit(sum, p, n - 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome. Interesting story, but what's your question?

Comment: Please note that `p / 100` is an *integer* division, with an integer result. For example `99 / 100` will be equal to `0`, as will all values between (and including) `0` and `99` divided by `100`.

Comment: Also note that the solution is not to simply use floating point, because then you will get too many decimals (instead of none).

Comment: 120 isn't correct anyway, 100 + 10% is 110 but another 10% is then 121. I'd find a better source of problems that can do basic maths

Comment: my question is how do i get 120 as my answer because I sent my teacher the code and I told her 120 is not possible but she said I should check my implementation

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If they want 120 as the answer then i guess they're expecting non-compound interest so just calculate the percentage based on the original amount though then doing it with a recursive function makes even less sense

Answer (score 0):

Since apparently the prof wants simple, not compound interest you can do this:

```
#include <iostream>

int deposit(int sum, int p, int n) {
    if (n == 0) {
        return sum;
    }
    else {
        int interest = sum * p / 100;
        return interest+deposit(sum, p, n - 1);
    }
}

int main()
{
    // one to three periods 110,120,130
    std::cout << deposit(100, 10, 1) << '\n';
    std::cout << deposit(100, 10, 2) << '\n';
    std::cout << deposit(100, 10, 3) << '\n';
}
```

While it's recursive, it's also kind of weird because you are adding exactly the same interest (simple interest) each time. This really isn't even an instructional application of recursion as the simple solution is just  this:

```
int deposit(int sum, int p, int n) {
    return sum + sum * n * p / 100;
}
```